# Dockerfile for GRAV CMS

Tags: php, content-management-system, dockerfile, grav

I am using [Grav](http://getgrav.org) for blog and CMS, it is really a good markdown/flat CMS system.

In the documents site of Grav, most of the deployment guide are targeting to hosted VPC or cloud VMs, however, I am thinking about a better way and would like to seek help here:

1. Edit the markdown file and git commit/push the content to github
2. Use docker to do the continuous delivery
3. To be specific, put a dockerfile under the root folder of Grav, config [docker public cloud] to automatically build Grav container image and push it to AWS when new commit happens on Github.

I am not good on PHP (Grav use PHP), so It is hard for me to write a good dockerfile for Grav. Could anyone give some hint or share a dockerfile for Grav? I am currently using this [one](https://github.com/frankyuyong/grav-prod/blob/master/Dockerfile) but it is extremely slow on docker image build and always failed the build.

Many thanks for your help and input!

Answer (score 1):

Hi i think you dont Need to rebuild your container every time. I think you need only this Plugin https://github.com/trilbymedia/grav-plugin-git-sync this Plugin syncs you content into your container or where ever you hosted your Grav installation.

For Container Hosting i use this docker Image https://github.com/NMathar/gravcms-docker/blob/master/README.md Check of it Fits your needs.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @FrankerZ i think a small answer is better then none. I hope its better now.